# Find out the list of tests that are skipped

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a huge project which has multiple tests which are skipped (either by mvn or using the @Ignore annotation). Is there a way I can use maven to show me all the tests that it is skipping (and not execute any test)?

Something like:

```
mvn test --show-skipped-tests
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at surefire report plugin : [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html)

It does display the tests which were skipped.

Comment: Seriously, the maven developer never thought that this was necessary without a plugin?!

Comment: Maven has modular architecture. Much important functionality is spread through plugins. Just a way to do it, I guess.